# Python Unicode Byte Decoding From File

Tags: python, encryption, unicode

I feel like an absolute idiot for posting this...

So, I'm making a file crypter that reads a text file, outputs it to an encrypted file, and then allows you to turn that file back into plaintext. I've got writing the file down, but reading it is a problem.

From the encryption:

```
newf.write(bytes(result[0], "utf-8"))
newf.write(bytes('{[:|:;:|:]}'))
newf.write(bytes(result[1], "utf-8"))
newf.close()
```

And also the decryption:

```
name = fudder.askopenfilename(defaultextension =("Text Files","*.txt"),title = "Choose a file to decrypt.")
    with open(name,'rb') as Usefile:
        filecont = bytes(Usefile.read(),'utf-8')
```

It brings up this error:

```
File "C:\STUFF\FILE.py", line 93, in <lambda>
    self.fileO = Button(text = 'Decrypt File', command = lambda: cryptFile())
  File "C:\STUFF\FILE.py", line 60, in cryptFile
    filecont = Usefile.read()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 68: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Have a look at `codecs.open` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html?highlight=open#codecs.open). It should allow you to specify the unicode encoding when opening the file, then transparently read its contents.

Comment: Is this python 2 or 3? How come the error you get isn't from the code you show? Would `filecont = Usefile.read().decode('utf-8')` work?

Comment: You should be able to write a runnable example for this problem. If we are going to test a solution it means we have to write one...

Answer (score 0):

The traceback shows that in your ***real*** code, the error occurs in the `cryptFile` function on this line:

```
    filecont = UseFile.read()
```

The `UnicodeDecodeError` indicates that `UseFile` is a file-like object that has probably been opened in text mode without specifying an encoding. This means it will try to use the default encoding of cp1252 (on Windows) to decode a file that has actually been encoded as UTF-8. Obviously, this will fail when the codec encounters any unmapped bytes (such as `0x81`).

The solution is to specify the correct encoding when opening the file:

```
    with open(name, 'rt', encoding='utf-8') as Usefile:
        filecont = UseFile.read()
```

This will result in `filecont` being a unicode string object.